# Python 2.7.10 Windows 7 and subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE flag with Popen stdin.write(); Not Working

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, popen

Here is my goal:

- Create a *new* python console using `subprocess.Popen()` with the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag.
- Write to its stdin and have it print to the new console.

On my windows 10 laptop I was able to get it working, however, on my Windows 7 Desktop, the process fails due to the `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`
I have also tried removing `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` and adding `shell=True` into the parameters. This fails to do anything.

Script.py:

```
CODE="""
import sys;
while 1:
    sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.readline());
    sys.stdout.flush();
""";
def Process():
    return Popen([sys.executable,'-c',CODE],stdin=PIPE,bufsize=1,universal_newlines=True,creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE);
p=Process();
p.stdin.write('Hello World\n');
p.stdin.flush();
raw_input('');
```

When I run this "script.py," quickly opens and closes a new console. The program is crashing at some point. The original console stays open:
`raw_input('');` keeps it from closing.

I have also tried `try:` and `except:` to prevent the new process from crashing, but instead just creates a blank console that doesn't do anything.
I've done a lot of research and there is nothing that addresses this issue that I have found.

UPDATE*** I updated to Python 2.7.15 and then continued to determine the issue.
I have found out that the `sys.stdout.flush();` is throwing a *[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor* error because *sys.stdout* is somehow corrupt.
My main question is "How can I preserve *stdout* in `subprocess.Popen()` so that the new console window can print to itself without the *stdout* being redirected?"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: capture the error message e.g., drop `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` so that the script runs in the same console.

Comment: I just removed the `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` and it did print _Hello World_ to my console. I had to close out of it due to the `while 1` loop. So this means it has to do with the new console.

Comment: So far I have come to the conclusion that _stdout_ is invalid and throws an _[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor_ error when calling `sys.stdout.flush();`. How then can I preserve the _stdout_ so that it prints to the new console?